# Output to console in run-time from future_map

Tags: r, r-future, furrr

I have following code which is supposed to run in parallel with furrr.

```r
plan(multisession)

1:10 %>% furrr::future_map(function(x) {
    print("Start")
    Sys.sleep(1)
    print("End")
    x
}, .progress = TRUE)
```

By specifying `.progress = TRUE` I can see progress of the operation in real-time. However all pairs of `Start...Stop` for all runs I will see only after completing whole function execution.

Is it possible to output anything to console during run and how?

Comment: You are running processes across multiple workers. Unless furrr does something totally different that I don't know, you won't be able to print the values from independent workers to screen in real-time.